# If I have a specific date of a day, how do I get the date of that day in the previous week?

Tags: java, datetime, date, calendar

SEE ANSWER FROM @Basil Bourque for most up to date answer

---

For example, if I have a "Date" variable "date1" with a value of (dd/mm/yyy) 03/07/2011, which is a Sunday. How do I get the "Date" of the previous Sunday "date2"? which would have the value (dd/mm/yyyy) 26/06/2011.

Is there an easy way of doing it, for example:

pseudo code:

```
Date date1 = (03/07/2011);
Date date2 = date1.subtractNumberOfDays(7);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.JULY , 3 )
         .minusWeeks( 1 )
```

> 2011-06-26

## java.time

The Question and Answers use old outmoded date-time classes. Instead use the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.JULY , 3 );
```

Alternatively, pass an integer in second argument instead of the `Month` enum. Pass 1-12 for January-December.

### Previous week

You can subtract a week from the date.

```
LocalDate weekPrior = localDate.minusWeeks( 1 );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/mtU2cq).

### Previous day-of-week

If you want a specific day of the week, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html).

Several such handy implementations provided in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) class (note the plural 's').

```
LocalDate priorTuesday = localDate.with( TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 34):

You should use Calendar:

```
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2011, Calendar.JULY, 3);
    date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
    System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

You can create a calendar from date too:

```
    Date date1 = new Date(111, Calendar.JULY, 3);//the year field adds 1900 on to it.
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    date.setTime(date1);
    date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
    date2 = date.getTime();
```

**Be aware that:**

- Java uses 0 to represent January !
- Date(year, month, day) is deprecated since JDK version 1.1 !

See the GregorianCalendar JavaDoc:

> Constructs a GregorianCalendar with the given date set in the default time zone with the default locale.
>   Parameters:
>   year the value used to set the YEAR calendar field in the calendar.
>   month the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the calendar. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.
>   dayOfMonth the value used to set the DAY_OF_MONTH calendar field in the calendar.

Comment: I would like to, but I am an intern working on a huge inhouse program that already uses Date (and Calendar :S but in this particular scenario it uses Date).

Comment: Just add: "Date dateAsDate = date.getTime();" to the end of the above code. dateAsDate is the Date object.

Comment: Ah thank you! This will be a big help! I will accept your answer as soon as the timer on the block runs out :)

Comment: You can also use more obvious cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);

Comment: The second method of creating a date `new Date(2011,3,7)` is deprecated.

Comment: Not only is it deprecated, you used it wrong. Unless you were wanting a date in the year 3911. The year goes from 1900, so 2011 would be 111.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some fixes, thanks for all comments noting issues out.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

A more clear approach:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 1);
date.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

use either `WEEK_OF_MONTH` or `WEEK_OF_YEAR`

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) it will be very easy.

An example:

```
DateTime toDay=new DateTime();
DateTime dateOfPreviousWeek=toDay.minusDays(7);
```

Another:

```
DateTime toDay = new DateTime(2011, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime dateOfPreviousWeek = toDay.minusDays(7);
```

You can get `java.util.Date` from DateTime as:

```
Date javaDate=jodaDateTime.toDate();
```